# how to remove a youtube link from a text block but leave other text

Tags: jquery, regex

I am using jquery to change a youtube link within a text block to an embedded video. However, I would also like to remove the link part of the content while leaving everything else after changing it to an iframe. for example, if the text block was "hi! check out this video /youtube url/" I would like it to change to "hi! check out this video". I am currently trying this but its not working

```
$(this).text().replace(/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([\w\-]{10,12})(?:&feature=related)?(?:[\w\-]{0})?/g, '');
```

Comment: are there elements on the page that are identical , but not youtube links?  I mean is it possible to just find the url and strip it out?  or are some youtube url's and some not?

Comment: Your regex works, [have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/t7yxrcs6/).

Comment: yea im using the exact same one to parse out the link elsewere in this code and it works. i'm not sure if its a problem with the replace call or what but im getting nothing replaced.

Comment: You are not assigning back the replacement result to the element.

Comment: could you explain how that would work?